# SQL merge two tables then remove entries based on a third list

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have two mailing lists that we need to combine, and then

1. make sure there are no duplicates
   and
2. compare against a 3rd list (the unsubscribe list) and remove any names that are on that list.

I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM [table1.EmailAddress FROM table1 union all 
        SELECT table2.Emailaddress FROM table2]. AS [email];
```

which works fine for the 1st problem. I then tried to add

```
where not exist (select table3.emailaddress from table3)
```

to that select query, to no avail...
We're using access 2000 ( no we won't upgrade);
The all tables have other fields, none of which match any other tables.
Even the emailaddress fields have non matching cases...

Comment: Maybe this is a copy-paste thing: that subquery / derived-table doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct email
from (
    select Email
    from Table1
    union all
    select Email
    from Table2
)x
where not exists(
    select * from table3 t3 where t3.Email=x.Email
)
```

If you have a case sensitive DB just `LOWER()` all the email columns.

Comment: +1 You can probably drop the `distinct` if you change `Union All` to just Union

Comment: I'm running this through now. It's taking quite a while - we have over 200k names combined and about 8.5k names on the unsubscribe list...

Answer (score 0):

Does Access 2000 support the minus operator?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [[table1.EmailAddress FROM table1 union all SELECT table2.Emailaddress FROM table2]. AS [email] MINUS SELECT table3.EmailAddress FROM table3]
```